B&W Thriller/Mystery with a mute girl in a mansion
Ok, I am going to give as much detail as I can remember. I have seen this black-and-white movie a long time ago, and it popped into my head today.
I remember a girl who might have lost her voice in a traumatic experience. She is living in a mansion-type of house and might be a maid/nurse? 
I remember a cellar, an older woman (who might have been the bad guy/girl). At the end the girl who cannot speak, goes into the phone booth in the house and calls for help, and at that part she finally gets her voice back to call for help.
The movie was a dark/mystery/thriller and there was this guy trying to solve the mystery.  

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points.  The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

The Spiral Staircase from 1945 with Dorothy McGuire and    Ethel Barrymore (who was nominated for an Oscar for the role).

Beautiful young mute Helen is a domestic worker for old ailing Mrs. Warren. Mrs. Warren's two sons, Albert (a professor) and womanizing impudent Steven, also live in the Warren mansion. Mrs. Warren becomes concerned for Helen's safety when a rash of murders involving 'women with afflictions' hits the neighborhood. She implores her physician, Dr. Parry, to take Helen away for her own safety. When another murder occurs inside the Warren mansion, it becomes obvious that Helen is in danger. 

In the end, Helen manages to ring the doctor for help and regains her voice. Here's the trailer:




No problem, but if the answer is correct, please approve it by clicking on the check mark next to it from your original account (instead of posting a comment as another answer).
